# Different definitions of the same lambda

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, closures

I've recently opened [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48241935/lambdas-captured-variable-is-reset) discussion, from which the following problem comes from. This question is a sort of continuous of that discussion. Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

std::function<int(void)> mylambda(int starter){
    return [starter]() mutable {
        return ++starter;
    };
}

void tester_wrapper(const std::function<int(void)>& cb, int counter){
    if (counter == 10)
        return;
    else{
        cout << cb() << endl;
        tester_wrapper(cb, counter + 1);
    }
}

void tester(const std::function<int(void)>& cb){
    tester_wrapper(cb, 0);
}

int main()
{
    auto getNum = mylambda(1);

    tester(getNum);
    tester(getNum);
}
```

In this case the code does what I expected, more specifically it prints all number from 2 to 21. However if my `main` function was like this:

```
int main()
{
    auto getNum = ([](int starter) {
        return [starter]() mutable {
            return ++starter;
        };
    })(1);

    tester(getNum);
    tester(getNum);
}
```

Then the output would be numbers from 2 to 11 repeated twice. I can't explain myself why it produces this output even if the only difference between the 2 pieces of code is where and how the `mylambda` function is defined.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because the lambda closure type and `std::function` are not reference related. Those are separate types. You can't bind a reference to `std::function` directly to a lambda object.

A lambda object is convertible to a `std::function` however. So what happens is that the compiler creates a temporary `std::function` that binds to that const reference. Creating very much the same situation in your original question. Because each call to `tester` necessitates another temporary object. Temporaries only live to the end of the full expression that makes them spring to life.

In the first code sample, you already have a `std::function` object in main. That one binds directly to the reference, so you are calling `tester` with the same referred-to object.

Comment: Thank you @StoryTeller, great explanation.